# How to make multiple plots using data in one column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Lets say I have the following data frame:

```
ID     amount_ID   timespan    change
3      1           20          2
3      2           40          3
3      3           60          6
3      4           80          4
3      5           100         5
9      1           25          1
9      2           50          -2
9      3           75          0
9      4           100         -1
3      1           33.33       4
3      2           66.67       8
3      3           100         7
9      1           33.33       1
9      2           66.67       3
9      3           100         4
```

I want to make 2 plots with this data, one for `ID` 3 and one for `ID` 9. The `timespan` should be on the x-axis and the `change` should be on the y-axis. As you can see the maximum length of the x-axis is 100 per `ID`. But I want to make a graph where the change is the average of all the previous changes in the past from that same `ID`. So essentially I need to add up all the changes per timespan per individual ID and divide that by the times a particular `ID` number is present. The problem is that the timespan can be different within a particular ID (here ID 3 first has 5 amounts and then has 3 amounts, ID 9 first has 4 amounts and then has 3 amounts).

[Here is a visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZSY5.png)

I hope you can help me!!! **Thanks!**

Comment: You list ggplot and r in the tags, so surely you've tried something? What did you try and what worked/didn't work? You'll probably need to do some preprocessing for the custom/non-standard logic, but let's take one step at a time and break down the problem

Comment: Yes I tried plotting it, but I am stuck at the part where an ID has different timespan numbers, If the numbers would be the same I could just add them all together and divide everything by the amount of ID segments I have, but now that is not possible.

Comment: Could you post the code that you used?

Comment: This link may be helpful [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cummean` to calculate the running average at each `timespan`. Also `facets`are useful to show every `ID` in separate plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(ID, timespan) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(change = cummean(change)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(timespan, change) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(.~ID, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you! Do you know how I can make plots where I only add them together when the final change is positive and another one where the final change is negative. So for ID 3 we have only 1 positive plot, but for ID 9 we have 1 negative plot and 1 positive plot.

Comment: You can ask this as new question.